# How can I share authentication between multiple CMSs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, content-management-system

How can I share authentication between multiple custom CMSs? I don't want the user with multiple CMS instances on multiple domains to have to create account for each CMS. Is there a way to create one account and use it across all CMSs for all websites? CMS is a custom MERN api.

EDIT: each CMS uses it's own database

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what language you are coding with but you should be able to store the user's credentials when they first give them then pass the values to the other CMSs when necessary.

If you go this route, I recommend encrypting the credentials when obtained and decrypting them just before they are used.

Comment: Wouldn't this create multiple sources of truth?

Comment: If you have different methods that would rely on the user credentials then it would not be an SSOT. Another option is If you would rather not store passwords as a variable, you can also pass the credentials to environment variables and then get them from all your methods where it is necessary. This would be good if you have your methods in different project folders.